# AWS StepFunctions - SendTaskSuccess/SendTaskFailure operation - Task time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to execute a step function that has a task that uses an activity resource.

and after running my code i would like to return a `SendTaskSuccess` or `SendTaskFailure`

back to the step function.

I'm getting the following error sporadically (after less then 10 seconds):

```
An error occurred (TaskTimedOut) when calling the SendTaskFailure operation: Task Timed Out: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:<....>'
```

where do i disable the TaskTimeOut? or how do i increase it?

**more info**

This is the step function code

```
{
  "Comment": "orchestrator-state-machine",
  "StartAt": "get_data_from_lambda",
  "States": {

    "get_data_from_lambda": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "start_task"
    },

    "start_task": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:<...>",
      "End": true
    }

  }
}
```

Code for sending success

```
self._client = boto3.client('stepfunctions', self._region, config=Config(connect_timeout=65,read_timeout=70,region_name=self._region))

...
def task_success(self, token, result):
    self.logger.info(str(token))
    try:
        self._client.send_task_success(taskToken=token, output=result)
        self.logger.info("sending success back to step function")
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.error("did not send success to step function: {0}".format(str(e)))

    return True
```

request details

```
{
  'Error': {
    'Message': "Task Timed Out: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:<....>t'",
    'Code': 'TaskTimedOut'
  },
  'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RequestId': 'b******d-755a-****-9cef-ad*******a4c',
    'HTTPStatusCode': 400,
    'HTTPHeaders': {
      'x-amzn-requestid': 'b******d-755a-****-9cef-ad*******a4c',
      'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
      'content-length': '154'
    },
    'RetryAttempts': 0
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code from where you are sending `SendTaskSuccess` or `SendTaskFailure`?

Comment: added code for SendTaskSuccess.

Comment: Looks good. So why are you sending `send_task_success`? Why can't you just exit the task normally?

Comment: need to return if the task finished successfully or if it failed to the step function

Comment: if an error occurs in your lambda function, task will fail and `Step Function` will stop the execution. You don't have to manually send `Success` or `Failure`. You can see the exception in `Exception` block of the task/activity.

Comment: the code above does not run as part of a lambda function. it runs on an EC2 instance that gets the activity from the step function and returns a success or fail back to the step function

Comment: Ok. makes sense now.

Comment: I am facing the same issue for sending task success, can anybody tell me how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked around and managed to reproduce the issue quite easily using [AWS command line interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Seems like it's an issue with AWS and it's now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can add timeout to activity step by adding `Timeout=300` where 300 would be time in seconds.

`"start_task": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:<...>",
      "Timeout":300,
      "End": true
    }`

Also you need make your the resouce arn is activity arn and not lambda function arn

Comment: The activity could be longer then X seconds. so timeout wasn't really an option.
think it was an issue with AWS. because I can't reproduce it anymore

Answer (score 0):

It may not apply here, but if your Step Function completes in under 30 seconds, you can use an Express Step Function (and `boto3.resource('stepfunction).start_sync_execution`) in order to wait for the response.

But I see from other responses you have that you may have very long response times.

The other option is to flip it, and use a script in your EC2 instance that you mentioned that polls the step function regularly (using the describe_execution boto3 method) and returns once it has a successful response.